# Pessimistic Lock not working using Spring Data and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I am writing an API to reserve resource.
I am using the following tech stack:

- Spring data jpa `2.7.3`
- MongoDB docker `mongo:6-jammy`
- Java `11`

The resource is limited so I need to check if resource is available then reserve it and update the DB. If there is not enough resource, then deny the request.

I have to run this service on multiple pods and there can be multiple request coming to reserve the resource at the same time.
I want to put a lock on document to avoid dirty read.

I have written a simple application which simulates my use case.

Entity:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "temp")
public class TempEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;

    private Integer tempResource;

    @Version
    private long version;

}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TempRepository extends MongoRepository<TempEntity, String> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Override
    Optional<TempEntity> findById(String id);

}
```

Service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class TempService {

    private final TempRepository tempRepository;

    @Transactional
    public TempEntity updateTempEntity(String id, Integer tempResource, String action) throws Exception {
        TempEntity te = tempRepository.findById(id).get();
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                // Wait for few seconds to test transaction easily
            }
        }
        if (action.equals("reserve")) {
            if (te.getTempResource() >= tempResource) {
                te.setTempResource(te.getTempResource() - tempResource);
                logger.info("successfully reserved");
            }
            else {
                logger.info("not enough resource");
            }
        }
        else {
            te.setTempResource(te.getTempResource() + tempResource);
        }
        return tempRepository.save(te);
    }

}
```

When I invoke two request at the same time, both are getting executed at same time.
One is getting successful, and another one is getting rejected. I am getting following exception for the failed request:

```
com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 112 (WriteConflict): 'WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {\"errorLabels\": [\"TransientTransactionError\"], \"ok\": 0.0, \"errmsg\": \"WriteConflict error: this operation conflicted with another operation. Please retry your operation or multi-document transaction.\", \"code\": 112, \"codeName\": \"WriteConflict\", \"$clusterTime\": {\"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1684146287, \"i\": 1}}, \"signature\": {\"hash\": {\"$binary\": {\"base64\": \"2L5+fO9qVbZS49TotZo7E7YhRNo=\", \"subType\": \"00\"}}, \"keyId\": 7205950246369624070}}, \"operationTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1684146287, \"i\": 1}}}
```

My expectation was that if I am writing a transactional method using `findById` which is annotated with `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)`, I should not have got this exception.

My second request should have waited for the previous transaction to get over, and the take the lock and read the document.